# Same segue for more actions in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to perform same segue on both table view row selection and bar button item tap actions. Is there any possibility to do it in IB (without code `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)`)?

I do not want do create brand new (same) segue for both actions. Just reuse the one. Something like wire it up with the existing one...

Comment: Why don't you use didselectrowatindexpath delegate method and place  performSegueWithIdentifier in it.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can do it without code.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple segues from one VC to another, but the catch is that they have to have unique segue identifiers. Just ctrl+drag from your table cell to the destination VC to create one, then do the same from your bar button item too create the other.